# sort multidimentional array by multiple value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have array like this,

```
Array
(
  [341] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2034
        [name] => Basic
        [file] => 577688a31d889.svg
        [order] => 12
    )

  [342] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2065
        [name] => Bold
        [file] => 579af7d384970.svg
        [order] => 0
    )

  [344] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2036
        [name] => Modern
        [file] => 577688a37fe1b.svg
        [order] => 10
    )

  [1869] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2066
        [name] => Professional
        [file] => 579af7d3c0774.svg
        [order] => 0
    )

  [335] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2033
        [name] => Favourites
        [file] => 577688a2e0502.svg
        [order] => 0
    )

  [1870] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2067
        [name] => traditional
        [file] => 579af7d3f231a.svg
        [order] => 0
    )
)
```

I want to sort it by `desc` for order. But if order is same then sort it by its name `asc`. And i also want to keep key of array. i tried some solutions but not worked well for me and in some solutions it waived key.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { 
    $rdiff = $a['order'] - $b['order'];
    if ($rdiff) return $rdiff; 
     return $a['name'] - $b['name']; 
});
```

so according to given array, output should be like this,
    `341, 344, 342 335, 1869, 1870`.

Comment: @NanaPartykar i updated my question

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `uasort`  and `strcasecmp` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array
uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['order'] == $b['order']){
        return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
    } else {
        return $b['order'] - $a['order'];
    }
});

print_r($arr);
```

[DEMO link](https://eval.in/614214)